# Facebook login name getting wrong successfully

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, ruby-on-rails-5

Currently, login of facebook is going well, I can get profile picture.

However, only getting name is not an ordinary name, it is displayed as 4f427j700ef46f2555e6.

How to get it

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
   where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
     user.provider = auth.provider
     user.email = auth.info.email
     user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
     user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
     user.avatar = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
     # If you are using confirmable and the provider(s) you use validate emails,
     # uncomment the line below to skip the confirmation emails.
     # user.skip_confirmation!
   end
 end
```

Display method

```
<h2><%= @user.name %></h2>
```

Why can not I get a name?
please tell me.

Comment: What have you tried? What libraries, if any, are you using? What is `auth.info`? Are there any other useful attributes, e.g `auth.info.first_name`? How can I reproduce your problem?

Comment: Have you googled the problem before posting here? What resources did you find? What did you not understand/could not get to work? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13356603/1954610) may be for the exact same problem?

Comment: I tried `auth.info.first_name`

Comment: It was successfully displayed. However, the full name is not displayed properly. like this `4f427j700ef46f2555e6`

Comment: Very high chance that you are doing a typo, something like `user.name = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]`, since `4f427j700ef46f2555e6` is a 20 character random string.

Comment: @DaichiDaichi *"It was successfully displayed; however, it was not displayed properly"* -- Huh??!! So based on that description, it almost certainly sounds like the problem lies *somewhere else* in your code - e.g. you're re-setting `user.name` in another location.